# Rapport syntax c# Only a assignment, call, increment, decrement, expectation and new object expressions can be used as statement

Tags: c#, syntax

I am a beginner in C# and have an error in my code

I had a variable

```
Session.GetBobbaz().PetData = "0 5 #fff";
```

which work fine. But I want to make the second number and the color randomly So I've done this:

```
 var random = new Random();
   var color = String.Format("#{0:X6}", random.Next(0x1000000)); 
   Random randNum = new Random();
   var race = randNum.Next(25);
   var typeanimal = 1; 
   Session.GetBobbaz().PetData = typeanimal, race, color;
```

PetData = **typeanimal, race, color;**
Those three are underlined and make the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property `PetData` is of type `string`. You should assign string to it. Simplest way to build string in some specific format is [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) method:

```
Session.GetBobbaz().PetData = 
    String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", typeanimal, race, color);
```

It gets string representation of each parameter you pass and puts them in format placeholders (by index).